# Failed to insert record. Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I have configured a Postgresql image in Docker and I opened this with PGAdmin4 and the connection to the server is working fine.  I also created a db called test for doing some testing.  I have the following script just to try and insert a simple row in a table:-

```
def insert_teams():
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                    password="123456",
                                    host="172.18.0.3",
                                    port="5432",
                                    database="testdb")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO Teams (ID, TEAM, POINTS) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
        record_to_insert = (5, 'Brazil', 950)
        cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)

        connection.commit()
        count = cursor.rowcount
        print(count, "Record inserted successfully into teams table")

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Failed to insert record into teams table", error)

    finally:
        # closing database connection.
        if connection:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

However I am getting an error:-

```
Failed to insert record into teams table connection to server at "172.18.0.3", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I have done some research and I think that most probably this is due to the postgresql.conf file not listening:-

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

However I have no idea where I can find this file since I have a docker image.

If this is the problem, how can I access this file?

Thank you for your help and time

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved this issue!  I had to change my connection to the localhost:-

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                    password="123456",
                                    **host="127.0.0.1"**,
                                    port="5432",
                                    database="testdb")
```

No idea why though since I thought I was connecting to the database inside the image of the container.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is *precisely* because you are connecting from *within the same machine*.